# JPA EntityManagerFactory don't override persistence.xml file

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

When I lunch the app it is not take these properties but the default properties in glassfish-ressource.xml. I'm using JPA with nebeans automatical generated beans and entities. I want switch database at runtime.

Here his my session class

```
package facade;
import entities.Tpe;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Emmanuel
 */
@Stateless
public class TpeFacade extends AbstractFacade<Tpe> {
    private EntityManager em;
     @Override
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {

    EntityManagerFactory emf=null;
    Map properties = new HashMap();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "jdbc:mysql://192.20.3.81:3306/piv?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.database", "piv");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "username");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "password");

    try {
         emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ConfigurationTPEPU", properties);
         System.out.println("emfznezizzhzz "+emf.getProperties() );
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    em = (EntityManager) emf.createEntityManager();
    return em ;
}


    public TpeFacade() {
        super(Tpe.class);
    }

}
```

and my persistence file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ConfigurationTPEPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/connexion81</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

the glassfish-ressources.xml content

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_piv_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="db1"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="gsmcom"/>
                <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/petroivoire?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>

        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/connexion81" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_piv_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: it is will be me pleasure if someone can help me. this three days that this problem stopped my progression. And sorry for my english

Comment: What exactly do you have a problem with? You defined a persistence-unit with some properties BUT then overrode them in the creation of the EMF, so it uses the overrides where necessary. Just like the Javadocs say it should

Comment: This is not good Java EE style what you are doing because you will not use connection pooling and the Stateless EJB will create a EntityManagerFactory per pool instance. Why do you want to switch the database and not use the data source?

Comment: the problème is that overrode that's take, i want override properties which in persistence.xml but it is not work

Comment: "override" means use those INSTEAD. That's the whole point of the word. If you don't want to override then don't pass in the overriding properties (the variable `properties`)!!

Comment: i don't understand what do you suggest @simas_ch

Comment: To be short. It's not the way to do that. What do you want to achieve? Do you have several app servers and need to change the database connection? Then use environment variables. Please tell me your requirements that I can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be understood that, for an **@EJB** the application server is here to  takes care of the inetiation of the @EJB but also the injection of the persistence.

The configuration used is that already available in the Glassfish domain (domain/config/domain.xml) and not theses properties of glassfish-ressource.xml file.

This means, for override the first config you've to use two persistences and :

1. switch between them programmatically (when the both are injected).
2. Or use **Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( jndiDataSource2NdUnitName ).createEntityManager();**  where jndiDataSource2NdUnitName is the 2nd unit name.

Comment: thank you very much lead, i understood it very well, but i have one probleme i want add a new database with out redoploy my app. Because with the method that you gave to add new database with obliged to modify the persistence.xml by adding the new database config. there isn't another method to add new database programmatically. thank you

Comment: According to specifications it is impossible to add a persistence unit in a dynamic way. But if you're not using an APP server, sorry i've not an idea.